# How to calculate the difference between column values of different records in grafana/postgres

Tags: postgresql, plot, grafana

I have Grafana and postgres installed and connected. I use grafana to display charts of data I add to postgres. My postgres database has a table with records from multiple sources. The schema looks like this:

```
time   | source | bid | ask
12:01  | bitmex | 10  | 11
12:01  | deribit| 10  | 11
12:02  | bitmex | 9   | 11
```

The exact times per source are different. I’m able to plot different lines for every source:

[image]

I’m looking to plot the difference (grouped per minute) of two different sources. I think I need to select grouped minutes where “source = x” and the same where “source = y” and subtract those, while keeping the time macros from Grafana in there to keep the whole thing speedy. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I don't think this is at all possible with the "graphical query builder" in grafana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to do this in grafana (subtracting two queries) and was able to do it with a postgres query (including grafana macros):

```
SELECT (first / second * 10000 - 10000) as spread, time
FROM 
  (
    SELECT   $__timeGroupAlias("time",$__interval,previous), avg(bid) AS "first"
    FROM     bbo_20s
    WHERE    $__timeFilter("time") AND market = 1
    GROUP BY time
  ) AS e
FULL JOIN 
  (
  SELECT   $__timeGroupAlias("time",$__interval,previous), avg(bid) AS "second"
  FROM     bbo_20s
  WHERE    $__timeFilter("time") AND market = 2
  GROUP BY time
  ) AS c 
USING ("time") ;
```

The result looks like this and is very performant:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar.  Instead of doing a join, I just did one query and did the math in the 1 query and returned the result I was looking for.

```
  floor(extract(epoch from finished)/20)*20 AS "time",
  first.value AS "value"
FROM (
  SELECT
    $__timeGroupAlias(finished,$__interval,0),
    finished,
    id,
    (extract(epoch from minion_jobs.finished) * 1000) - (extract(epoch from minion_jobs.created) * 1000) AS value
  FROM minion_jobs
  WHERE queue = 'parallel'
  GROUP BY value,minion_jobs.finished, id
)AS first
```